# PHP Parsing JSON data into variables

Tags: php, arrays, json

Alright i have been searching all over this website for some simplistic help.
A lot of the examples here are so wrapped in code it's hard to get the understanding
to implement into my own code.

I need to loop through stats on each game and display the information via variables.
Now i can do everything myself, i just can't seem to find a for each loop willing to
display my information

My current code:

```
$ch2 = curl_init(); 
// set url 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/" . $myid . "/ranked?season=SEASON4&api_key=(REMOVED)"); 
//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
// $output contains the output string 
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2); 
// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch2);
$obj = json_decode($response2, true);
foreach ($obj as $val) {
echo "<b>" . $val['stats']['totalDeathsPerSession'] . "</b><br>";
echo "<b>" . $val['stats']['totalDamageTaken'] . "</b><br>";
echo "<b>" . $val['stats']['totalChampionKills'] . "</b><br>";
echo "<b>" . $val['stats']['totalDeathsPerSession'] . "</b><br>";
}
```

Here's the JSON data

```
{
"modifyDate": 1402869729000,
"champions": [
{
"id": 40,
"stats": {
"totalDeathsPerSession": 5,
"totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
"totalDamageTaken": 17488,
"totalQuadraKills": 0,
"totalTripleKills": 0,
"totalMinionKills": 15,
"maxChampionsKilled": 0,
"totalDoubleKills": 0,
"totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 6183,
"totalChampionKills": 0,
"totalAssists": 12,
"mostChampionKillsPerSession": 0,
"totalDamageDealt": 21580,
"totalFirstBlood": 0,
}
},
{
"id": 42,
"stats": {
"totalDeathsPerSession": 6,
"totalSessionsPlayed": 1,
"totalDamageTaken": 10626,
"totalQuadraKills": 0,
"totalTripleKills": 0,
"totalMinionKills": 29,
"maxChampionsKilled": 1,
"totalDoubleKills": 0,
"totalPhysicalDamageDealt": 11166,
"totalChampionKills": 1,
}
],
"summonerId": 29283170
}
```

it keeps going on and on, i don't want to flood the entire log here.
I am simply just trying to grab some of the data like Total Minion Kills
Total Deaths, Kills.. But it keeps coming up blank with everything i try.
I have attempted so many different ways before coming here. i really hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
foreach ($obj['champions'] as $val) {
```

Comment: haha, everytime i tried that method...i was getting an error in my foreach loop... However i am thinking maybe i tried the obj['stats'] and it created a fatal error?? i tried the obj['champions'] and it actually works.. I am very thankful.. you have saved my head much damage!! ty!